# How to specify a column field as offset in frame clause redshift window_functions?

Tags: amazon-redshift, window-functions

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
       SUM(nvl (quantity,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY customer_id,Billing_Month ASC ROWS BETWEEN (trailing_period-1) PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) / trailing_period::FLOAT AS Rolling_3_months_purchase
```

So, basically instead of manually specifying :

```
ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
```

I want it to be picked up from an integer column in the underlying table.

But I get an error like this:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near
```

Is it even possible to do this? From Redshift documentation it seems implausible. Is there a workaround?

> offset identifies a physical number of rows before or after the current row. In this case, offset must be a constant that evaluates to a positive numeric value. For example, 5 FOLLOWING will end the frame 5 rows after the current row.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this, not without dynamic SQL (does Redshift even support that?).

Comment: no, not supported

Comment: you have to use a join instead, unfortunately